# How can I remap autocompletion in vim?

Tags: vim, autocomplete

I'm using AutoComplPop with omnifunc.

Rather than <kbd>Enter</kbd> auto-completing the selection in the autocomplete popup, I'd like to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (or some other combination) and have <kbd>Enter</kbd> behave as usual.

That last point is important: if I want to insert a carriage return and the autocomplete popup has something highlighted, I'll have to hit enter twice.

So: **how can I remap the autocompletion key?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that the AutoComplPop plugin does anything to the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key; rather, this is the default behavior when the completion popup is visible. See `:h popupmenu-keys`:

> ```
>   The behavior of the <Enter> key depends on the state you are in:
>   first state:      Use the text as it is and insert a line break.
>   second state:     Insert the currently selected match.
>   third state:      Use the text as it is and insert a line break.
> ```

It's just that AutoComplPop by default selects the first match (which the built-in completions don't do).

To answer your question (though I don't fully get what behavior you want):

There's no special mode for the popup menu, you have to use a `:help map-expr` and check for the popup menu with `pumvisible()`. For example, to make `<Enter>` abort completion and insert a line break:

```
:inoremap <expr> <CR> pumvisible() ? '<C-e><CR>' : '<CR>'
```

Comment: This sort of works, but it's not compatible with some other plugins (e.g. endwise, which I use religiously). Still, I think it's likely to be the best answer. Not sure why it was downvoted.

After much trying to fix the problem (with conflicts) I've just moved to YouCompleteMe instead.